# ruby while loop translated to haskell

Tags: haskell

I've just started learning a bit of Haskell and functional programming, but I find it very difficult getting a hang of it :)

I am trying to translate a small piece of [ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) code to Haskell (because I like the concept functional programming and Haskell proposes and even more because I come from a mathematics field and Haskell seems very mathematical):

```
class Integer
  def factorial
    f = 1; for i in 1..self; f *= i; end; f
  end
end

boundary = 1000
m = 0

# Brown Numbers - pair of integers (m,n) where n factorial is equal with square root of m

while m <= boundary

    n = 0

    while n <= boundary
        puts "(#{m},#{n})" if ((n.factorial + 1) == (m ** 2)) 
        n += 1
    end

    m += 1
end
```

I could only figure out how to do factorials:

```
let factorial n = product [1..n]
```

I cannot figure out how to do the while loops or equivalent in Haskell, even though I found some examples that were far to confusing for me.

The idea is that the loops start from `0` (or `1`) and continue (with an increment of 1) until it reaches a boundary (in my code is `1000`). The reason there is a boundary is because I was thinking of starting parallel tasks that do the same operation but on different intervals so the results that I expect are returned faster (one operation would be done on `1` to `10000`, another on `10000` to `100000`, etc.).

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help out with this :)

Comment: On the very basic level `[1..n]` generates a list of indices that a normal loop would give you. If each iteration produces on element, use  a `map`. If you need to combine the iterations into one element, use a `fold`

Comment: @bartekbanachewicz ~ I confused `[1..n]` with a [range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Range.html) of numbers in ruby, or is it the same thing but it can also be used instead of loop?

Comment: It's a range of numbers alright, but there are tools to apply some operation on every element of a range. I just pointed out that `[1..n]` are values of index in a typical `for` loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
let results =  [(x,y) | x <- [1..1000], y <- [1..1000] ,1 + fac x == y*y]
               where fac n = product [1..n]
```

This is a list comprehension. More on that [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension).

To map it to your Ruby code,

1. The nested loops in `m` and `n` are replaced with `x` and `y`. Basically there is iteration over the values of `x` and `y` in the specified ranges (1 to 1000 inclusive in this case).
2. The check at the end is your filter condition for getting Brown numbers.
3. `where` allows us to create a helper function to calculate the factorial.

Note that instead of a separate function, we could have computed the factorial in place, like so:

```
(1 + product[1..x]) == y * y
```

Ultimately, the `(x,y)` on the left side means that it returns a list of tuples `(x,y)` which are your Brown numbers.

OK, this should work in your .hs file:

```
results :: [(Integer, Integer)] --Use instead of `Int` to fix overflow issue
results =  [(x,y) | x <- [1..1000], y <- [1..1000] , fac x == y*y]
        where fac n = product [1..n]
```

Comment: ``fac n = product`` does not compile. Change it to ``fac n = product[1..n]``

Comment: My bad. Missed it earlier.

Comment: Holy moly, this is so much less code than any other languages I tried :)

Comment: I get a `parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)` whenever I try to `:load eg.hs` in `ghci`, do you know what is that about?

Comment: Yeah, I think the indentation here isn't quite right. I don't have GHCi on my dev box at home, so I can't test at the moment, but I think you should be able to get it working using the second version of `factorial`.

Comment: I just get something in the output that does not make sense at all: for instance a pair of (1, 69); that must be wrong because `69! + 1 == 1*1` is not correct. Do you have a clue about what is going on there?

Comment: I need to check this. Gimme some time. It seems to be throwing out garbage after x = 65.

Comment: @rolandjitsu You are getting integer overflow. Replace `Int` by the unbounded `Integer` throughout.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen That's it. Take a bow, sir!

Comment: Yes, that made it work :) Though I do not get the difference between `Int` and `Integer` ...

Comment: @rolandjitsu `Int` is a type that is limited in size to a machine word, for speed and space efficiency, so it overflows when you get over that limit. `Integer` is a type that's based (usually) on the GMP bignum library, it can grow to several megabytes in size.

Answer (score 0):

To add to shree.pat18's answer, maybe an exercise you could try is to translate the Haskell solution back into Ruby.  It should be possible, because Ruby has ranges, `Enumerator::Lazy` and `Enumerable#flat_map`.  The following rewritten Haskell solution should perhaps help:

```
import Data.List (concatMap)

results :: [(Integer, Integer)]
results = concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> test x y) [1..1000]) [1..1000]
    where test x y = if fac x == y*y then [(x,y)] else []
          fac n = product [1..n]
```

Note that Haskell `concatMap` is more or less the same as Ruby `Enumerable#flat_map`.