# run haskell operations in parallel or multithreaded

Tags: multithreading, haskell, parallel-processing

I have just started learning functional programming and Haskell and am I not even close to understanding the syntax and how it works because it is very different from what I have been used to before (ruby, php, C# or node for instance, which are OOP languages - more or less).

I am am trying to put together a small program that checks for solutions for [Brocard's Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard's_problem) or so called **Brown Numbers** and I first created a draft in ruby, but I discovered that Haskell is much more appropriate for doing mathematical expressions. I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862938/ruby-while-loop-translated-to-haskell) previously and I got an answer pretty quick on how to translate my ruby code to Haskell:

```
results :: [(Integer, Integer)] --Use instead of `Int` to fix overflow issue
results =  [(x,y) | x <- [1..1000], y <- [1..1000] , 1 + fac x == y*y]
    where fac n = product [1..n]
```

I changed that slightly so I can run the same operation from and up to whatever number I want, because the above will do it from `1` up to `1000` or any hardcoded number but I would like to be able to decide the interval it should go through, ergo:

```
pairs :: (Integer, Integer) -> [(Integer, Integer)]
pairs (lower, upper) =  [(m, n) | m <- [lower..upper], n <- [lower..upper], 1 + factorial n == m*m] where factorial n = product [1..n]
```

The reason I ask this questions is that I was thinking if I could run this operations in parallel (and/or on multiple threads and/or cores) and append the results to the same variable.

I have not yet understood the parallel processing in Haskell or the threading model, but in ruby a good example of how the threading model works is something like [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_multithreading.htm):

```
def func1
  i=0
  while i<=2
    puts "func1 at: #{Time.now}"
    sleep(2)
    i=i+1
  end
end

def func2
  j=0
  while j<=2
    puts "func2 at: #{Time.now}"
    sleep(1)
    j=j+1
  end
end

puts "Started At #{Time.now}"
t1=Thread.new{func1()}
t2=Thread.new{func2()}
t1.join
t2.join
puts "End at #{Time.now}"
```

And in my case, the `func1` and `func2` would be the same function `results` computed on different intervals (`[1..1000] -> [i..j]`).

I would appreciate some help with this as I am not capable of doing it myself at this point :)

Comment: If you want to figure it out on your own, I'd suggest reading [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/index.html) by Simon Marlow.  You can buy the book or just read it online for free at that link.  He has a very good coverage of the different techniques you can use in Haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/pcph/) has a lot of good information, and [async](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async) is a good library for this stuff.

At the bottom level though, you'll find [`forkIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkIO) to start a new lightweight thread.

Of course that's *concurrency*, not deterministic parallelism, [parallel](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel) is the library for that, and also covered in the book.

Your example translates to:

```
import Data.Time.Clock (getCurrentTime)

main = do
    start <- getCurrentTime
    putStr "Started At " >> print start
    _ <- forkIO func1
    _ <- forkIO func2
    end <- getCurrentTime
    putStr "End at " >> print end

func1 = helper "func1" 2

func2 = helper "func2" 1

helper name sleepTime = go 0
 where
    go 3 = return ()
    go n = do
        now <- getCurrentTime
        putStr name >> putStr " at: " >> print now
        threadDelay sleepTime
        go $ succ n
```

I recommend learning the parallel and/or async libraries mentioned above, though, instead of writing your own threading stuff, at least initially.

Here's a not-so-great example of running tests on 8-ish processors using parallel:

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

factorial = product . enumFromTo 1
pairs (lower, upper) =  map fst . filter snd . withStrategy sparkTest
                     $ [ ((m, n), b)
                       | m <- [lower..upper]
                       , n <- [lower..upper]
                       , let b = 1 + factorial n == m*m
                       ]
sparkTest = evalBuffer 8 $ evalTuple2 rseq rpar
```

Comment: If the library is a built in module of Haskell it would be great, otherwise I tend to avoid 3rd party dependencies for such a simple requirement, unless necessary.

Comment: @rolandjitsu You'll find that much of Haskell is packaged into small, separate packages.  `base` includes only the absolute base libraries needed for Haskell development, but it doesn't include things like `containers`, which have `Map`s, `HashMap`s, and other standard structures.  They aren't necessarily 3rd party, since many of these come with the Haskell Platform.  The Haskell Platform is simply a set of community libraries considered stable, widely useful, and ubiquitous.  The `parallel` library comes with the [Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/changelog.html).

Comment: I would appreciate if you give a code example of how to use those two libraries (async and parallel) in conjunction with the function `pairs` I added in the question description

Comment: I tried the example (imported `Control.Parallel`) but it fails to compile when I `:load file.hs` in `ghci`.

Comment: @rolandjitsu Some minor mistakes in the example that should be fixed now, including the correct import.

Comment: It works now, it seems to be using all my processor cores, and it looks like it bounces the process from core to core, it doesn't look like it uses the same load on all cores at the same time.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, could you explain why use all the `map fst . filter snd`, because I find it hard to follow what is going on there

Comment: @rolandjitsu `filter snd` takes a list of pairs, and keeps (`filter`) only the ones where the second member (`snd`) is True.  `map fst` take a list of pairs and give a list of only their first member (`fst`).  Regarding the inconsistent load, I'm not sure exactly why it is uneven but I don't know that my strategy was any good, so you might come up with your own on top of suggestions from Zeta's answer.